# Autofocus TextField inside a TabView (DefaultTabController) in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am relatively new to Flutter (I don't know Dart, Java or any OOP languages) and creating a simple app using `DefaultTabController`.

My widget tree on my `InputScreen` roughly looks like this :

```
DefaultTabController
└── Scaffold
    ├── AppBar
    │   └── TabBar
    └── TabBarView
        ├── ListBox
        ├── ListBox
        ├── ListBox
        └── ListBox
```

A `ListBox` is a stful widget to hold my `ListViewBuilder`, and a `MessageBar` / `TextField`.

The behaviour I want to achieve is when users changing the Tab from one to another, the text field inside the TabBarView -> ListBox -> MessageBar gets autofocus so users don't need to tap on it. **Plus**, the text that already written on previous Tab still exists.

[image: retrospective app using defaulttabcontroller]

### What I tried so far :

#### Using TabController and add it to both TabBarView and TabBar

I add `with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin` on my ListBoxState and set tabController.addListeners() on initState().

```
final TabController tabController = TabController;
...
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    tabController = TabController(vsync: this, length: 4);
    tabController.addListener(() {
        print(tabController.index);
        // What to do here ?
    });
  }
}
```

#### FocusNode

I set the FocusNode inside each ListBox and after a Tab is initiated, I called the

```
    myFocusNode.requestFocus()
```

Didn't work (?). Should I make a different "myFocusNode" for each `ListBox`? I can not get the concept correctly :(

I put my current `input_screen.dart` file on [my gist](https://gist.github.com/prabowomurti/67d8d3d3359a8d88980930cf1c780fc9)

Answer (score 0):

You can to do:

```
@override
void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) =>FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(myFocusNode));
}
```

Comment: What and when to set the `myFocusNode` var? Do I need to differ 4 FocusNode and set it to each ListBox?

Comment: You must be defined myFocusNode: final FocusNode myFocusNode= FocusNode(); and assign it to TextField(focusNode: myFocusNode,)